# Profile Unit test code which is written is cpp

Tags: c++, profile

Is there any way we can profile unit test cases which are written for cpp program. I have implemented code coverage using gcov

Comment: You've tagged the question c++, so I presume that by "cpp" you mean c-plus-plus and not the c pre-processor.  But "cpp" is the C pre-processor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned gcov, how about gprof, will that work for you?